# how to add Home menu in magento home page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, wamp

How to add Home menu in magento home page. I add the code In this location
magento\app\design\frontend\default\grayscale\template\catalog\navigation

```
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
    <?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?>
  </a>
</li>
```

But home menu not displayed on the home page of Magento

Comment: have clear the cache? it might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the categories you want to display in menu under the root directory.

There may be more cases possible on why menu is not appearing.

Please consider following these guides : 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/enable_top_menu_navigation

http://www.atwix.com/magento/how-to-add-a-new-item-to-the-navigation-menu/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4z1RyyFHhU

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the template you're store is using?

You can check by enabling template hints in the developer section of the admin area.

this will hiliight all the blocks/templates for you and show the path to each file used. You will be able to check if the template you have modified is the template being used.